# How to reverse a string USING a MACRO that swaps the characters together with a stack in assembly language?

Tags: string, assembly, stack, reverse, swap

I need to use this:

```
SWAP    MACRO   A, B
    XOR     A, B
    XOR     B, A
    XOR     A, B
endm
```

---

I need to prompt the user to write a string
then i need to write a method or procedure that reverse the string
using the stack.
like:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV  EBP, ESP
```

..something like that.

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried or where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The stack reverses automatically, it's a first-in last-out system

So with "help"

Your macro needs to push push push push (h-e-l-p) goes in

and pop pop pop pop (p-l-e-h) comes out

You don't need xor for this one (unless you want to make things difficult)

XOR simply swaps registry entries which on a variable length user string would be a pain to control and would need to be combined with pointing